# Filter table records based on array of row ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hey guys i have a small issue . A little bit of context i have a table with checkboxes . Each row contains an ID when selected i recieve something like this

```
const mySelectedRoles = [1997,1998,1999]
```

Once selected i am filtering on my existing data so that i can find a match and send back the ID with the data behind each row to the parent .

```
setSelectedRowsData(
    tableData.rows.filter(obj=> obj.rowId === mySelectedRoles)
    )
```

The result that is coming back is an empty Array . Can someone give me a hand ? I will be grateful . Thaks

Comment: use ==  i thing it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point is to filter those table records that have `rowId` [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in `mySelectedRoles`, it has to be something, like:

```
setSelectedRowsData(
    tableData.rows.filter(obj=> mySelectedRoles.includes(obj.rowId))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet you are comparing the `obj.rowId` with the whole array instead of checking if it contains the ID. You need to use something like [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead:

```js
setSelectedRowsData(
    tableData.rows.filter(obj=> mySelectedRoles.includes(obj.rowId))
)
```